# Disable Windows Update-Windows 10 v1709

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update, windows-10-v1709

I'm running Win10 1709 Home. When I try to disable windows update service by stopping the services first then disabling service, it stops, but upon rebooting services comes back as if nothing had been done.

I tried the following power shell command in admin mode and still same result

```
stop-service wuauserv
set-service wuauserv –startup disabled
```

When I try to disable from Registry, Win10 Home does not have the following Registry Folder to enter reg keys

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\
```

Any help to accomplish this is greatly appreciated

Comment: You cannot block or defer windows updates on Windows 10 Home unless they are not compatible with your hardware which isn’t the case based on your description

Comment: How would one determine if they are not compatible and let the update service know? When we had Windows update fail in the past (Win 7 and prior), it just that after an update the system did not boot anymore. Could Windows 10 have gotten smarter?

Comment: @Itai Hardware determines if a feature update is compatible and there is only a few select devices that can’t run anything greater than 1607.  Windows Updates **cannot** be deferred on Windows 10 Home

Comment: @Ramhound use the WindowsUpdateMinitool from my answer in the duplicate, here you can hide Feature Update. I do this on my Home edition on my tablet.